# How to update a layout element's visibility with data binding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, data-binding

I'm having a hard time understanding how to update the view using data binding. I have a simple example I'm experimenting with, in which a toggle switch will make a button appear/disappear in the view.

**Expected behavior:**
The toggle button should toggle the "Add Key" button on/of (i.e. `VISIBLE` or `GONE`).

**Actual behavior:**
The "Add Key" button's visibility does not get updated. It only gets set once when the layout is loaded.

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="mainActivity"
            type="tanager.sandbox.MainActivity" />

        <variable
            name="businessLogic"
            type="tanager.sandbox.BusinessLogic" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="tanager.sandbox.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_key_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="@{businessLogic.getVisible()}"
                android:text="@string/add_key" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="ToggleButton"
            android:onClick="@{() -> mainActivity.click()}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

When the toggle button is pressed, it invokes a method on the main activity, which toggles a value in the business logic. I'm expecting the `add_key_button` to update its visibility automatically when the toggle button is pressed. Here is the `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BusinessLogic _businessLogic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        _businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
                R.layout.activity_main);

        binding.setMainActivity(this);
        binding.setBusinessLogic(_businessLogic);
    }

    public void click() {
        _businessLogic.toggleVisibility();
    }
}
```

And here is the business logic class:

```
public class BusinessLogic extends BaseObservable {

    private boolean visible;
    public BusinessLogic(){
        visible = true;
    }

    public void toggleVisibility(){
        visible = !visible;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.visible);
    }

    @Bindable
    public int getVisible(){
        return visible? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly refactored your code, this works

```
public void click() {
    _businessLogic.toggleVisibility(binding.toggleButton.isChecked());
}
```

The BusinessLogic method now looks like

```
public class BusinessLogic extends BaseObservable {

private boolean isToggleOn;

public BusinessLogic() {
    isToggleOn = false;
}

public void toggleVisibility(boolean toggleOn) {
    isToggleOn = toggleOn;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.toggleOn);
}

@Bindable
public boolean getToggleOn() {
    return isToggleOn;
}
```

Then in the layout, you can set the visibility based on the `getToggleOn` method of the businessLogic class

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/add_key_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="@{businessLogic.toggleOn ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add key" />
```

Remember to import the view class in your layout

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="mainActivity"
        type="stackoverflow.MainActivity" />
```